# Wouldn't it be beneficial to write tests during code review?

Tags: programming-practices, unit-testing, testing, teamwork, workflows

A colleague of mine came up with an idea that I found interesting.

**Wouldn't it be beneficial to write tests during code review, by the person doing the review assuming that we don't do TDD?**

For this question assume that this is a purely academic project so there is no life at stake. Moreover the team is 4 people. Everyone knows the language and is familiar with all the tools/libraries/frameworks used and can write tests. So basically people who are not senior fullstack lead ninja engineers but decent coders.

Pros I found:

1. Encourages deeper understanding of code during review to write meaningful tests.
2. You could then add code review of those tests done by the author of the code being tested.

Cons I found:

1. Feedback loop between code writing and testing grows.

EDIT: I know that it won't work well on "normal" web applications. What I had in mind was a corner case where you implement complex, scientific algorithms that require care to the details. Let's assume something like implementing my own graph library, NLP etc. I wonder if the code we are writing is isolated from databases and such but very tough to comprehend wouldn't the added level of control, the other person who needs to understand the source code and do meaningful test, make the whole process less prone to those less obvious bugs that don't crash the application but ultimately make your results rubbish?

Comment: You don't mention whether this raft of testing would be over and above the testing that should occur during development or in place of.

Comment: I thought about no tests during developement if something is wrong it is revealed during code review and both developer and reviewer sit together to solve the matter. If everything is all right, tests pass then developer review the tests that reviewer wrote to see if they both agree on the feature and tests if no then they sit together to solve the matter.

Comment: It would be benefitial but rather difficuilt to write unittest (tests-in isolotaion) if "we don't do TDD" because non tdd-code is usually hard to isolate. Writing Acceptance tests and/or integration test will also be difficuilt and/or fragile if you donot have an database abstraction layer (repository api) that allows you to define reproducable, non fragile pre-conditions.

Comment: There are some places where it is considered a bad practice when tests are written by the same person who wrote the code. That's because for some reasons if i test my own code i'm more likely to make tests that works

Comment: @JoulinRouge Agreed - but the inference here is that it is bad practice when *all* of the testing is carried out by the developer...

Comment: @JoulinRouge: TDD helps with that. Since there is no code, you cannot tailor the test to your code.

Comment: Am I reading your question and comments correctly as "We aren't doing TDD, because nobody else wants to, but need to do testing.  Wouldn't it be beneficial to do testing at some point?"  It seems the answer is an unequivocal **yes** via propositional logic, unless there's actually a strong aversion to testing in general, not just TDD.  It's a tautology that "If you need to do testing, and you wont do testing in phase A, you need to do testing in some phase besides A"

Comment: This sounds like it would be a REALLY long code review.

Comment: So you want somebody to write tests for some code that they are not going to like, expect them not to make changes so the code can be tested to their expectations, magically interpret the purpose of the code to be the same as the original implementer and not end up with a major rewrite in the process? Good luck with that. The real solution is to get rid of the developers who don't test their own code adequately. Also, what software developer in their right mind is going to want to spend their days writing tests for other people's code on a regular basis?

Comment: I've worked at places where a peer review involved a fellow programmer looking over every line you've written, checking them against style guidelines and best practices, and writing the unit tests you didn't think to write.

Comment: While this may be good, having the developer write the tests is even better.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - I've worked those places to with the exception of writing the unit tests. Instead, the review would just have a comment saying you should add unit tests for conditions a, b and c. The biggest issue with peer reviewing code (and the OP's suggestion) is that for most code the reviewer needs to have a good understanding of what the code is supposed to do in the context of the system. That frequently takes a lot of time to be effective. There's been much beautifully written and bug-free code that passed review that didn't do what it needs to do in the system.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich to be clear, you didn't even get to submit code if you didn't write your own unit tests.  The peer reviewer supplemented your tests with their own. They certainly didn't do your unit testing for you.  They just pointed out what you missed. If you did your job right they wouldn't add anything.

Comment: @Dunk I actually spent a lot of time developing our testing capabilities so we could easily exercise the systems real needs rather than just write *this goes in and that comes out* tests.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - Good testing is certainly obtainable.  In order to do what you said then you'd need tests at a higher level than unit tests, which is what I always advocate. Tests are expensive to write and expensive to maintain. Testing at the module/package level or even system level provides far more bang for the buck than unit tests and tends to reveal how the code is really used in the system.

Comment: @dunk I'm pro testing.  Early, late, low, high, unit, integration, module.  I welcome a test the moment someone thinks of it. I only ask for lose coupling to implementation and automation.  Most test based misery I've seen comes from not respecting these two testing principles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ## Wouldn't it be beneficial to write tests during code review, by the person doing the review?

I have found that a good time to write tests is when you realize you need a test for a situation.

Task switching for computers is expensive - even more-so for humans.

At this point in time, you generally have a good understanding of the requirements and dependencies for the test. So leverage your team's immersion in the problem. If you need to refine your new test in the future, great, you already have the test framework/fixtures in place, and all you need to do is change the part that needs improvement.

If that happens during code review, why not go ahead and do that? I've done that before. I've found that it's better than not, especially if you can do it quickly, and even better if you wouldn't have done it otherwise.

> ### Assuming that we don't do TDD?

Even if you do practice TDD, if you realize you need a test while doing code review, one that you don't have, why not write the test then and there?

### Pros

- You leverage your focus on the code under review.
- Sometimes code review becomes hang-out and chat time when people aren't into it. Writing a test encourages everyone to more actively think about the code being reviewed.
- More junior members of the team will have an opportunity to learn from the test-writing experience.
- You may identify talent on your team that you didn't know you had.

Is it really a con that more tests may lead to more code? If the test was needed, and the code was needed for the test, and now you have it, then that's a *good* thing.

### Caveats

Maybe some of the team needs to be focused on other things. If it causes a distraction from priorities, or your code review goes over schedule, then you need to limit or cut the actual writing of the test out. However, code review can certainly identify tests that need to be written, and perhaps they can at least be stubbed out for the writer to complete later.

Answer (score 22):

This is a wonderful idea, with one caveat. Don't replace developer written tests with reviewer written tests. Have your reviewers look for corner cases and inputs that will break the code. In other words, have them try to write *new tests* that the original developer didn't think to write.

Writing characterization tests is an absolutely wonderful way to gain an understanding of a piece of code you didn't write. Having your reviewers drive additional tests at the code gives them a much better understanding of how the code works, how it can be broken, and how it can be improved. All the while, increasing your code coverage.

These are all wins in my book.

Comment: It's almost like you have experience reviewing code...

Comment: No idea what you're talking about @syb0rg... You can't prove it. =;)-

Comment: [*cough*](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41243/rubberduck?tab=profile) ;-)

Comment: Also, a test case is just about the least ambiguous way of describing a flaw discovered in review :-)

Comment: @syb0rg Rubber Duck has [helped thousands or millions of programmers fix their code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Who is better qualified to review code than one who has seen so much?

Answer (score 18):

I don't think the idea is entirely without merit - however, the main benefit of the TDD et al is that problems are found *early*. The developer is also best placed to spot which corner cases may require specific attention. If this is left until the code review, then there is a risk this knowledge could be lost.

Writing tests during the code review would suffer from the same problem as traditional manual testing - the understanding of the business rules can vary from developer to developer as can the diligence.

There is also the age old discussion which will run and run as to whether developers would test their code so well if they knew there was a testing function further upstream that should catch the more serious bugs.

Comment: Great answer. But what if we won't do TDD because the people don't want to and I have no leverage over them but we need to make sure that the result we get are not false positives because an error skewed our results? The main risk is that people might rush to implement something without proper understanding, write tests with that improper understanding in mind making tests pass but ultimately producing wrong code. Maybe pair programming would solve the matter? But then again it is easy to force ones understanding of something on someone.

Comment: I think perhaps as well as someone else writing the tests, these could be run against development code whilst development is in progress. The developers in question would need to be on the same page as to where the code is at otherwise the developer writing the code could be constantly fire-fighting failed tests rather than actually getting the thing working.

Comment: The problem is called "Conformational Bias".

Comment: In fact I would say it, distracted from the code review process and the code would affect the testing process, which is not what you want, taking away the key advantage of having a separate tester and coder.

Comment: "as can the diligence" Writing tests up front suffers from this particular problem as well.

Comment: It also depends on when the review happens. If it happens the “traditional” way (i.e. at the end of project, often pushed _after_ the actual delivery—been there), it's way too late. If it happens the “modern” way before integration of each task, the gap is not big. However, I suspect if @Sok can't push TDD, they might not be able to push review before integration either.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, but if the dev writes the tests then they are at fault if an issue is identified when it goes live. If the code reviewer writes the tests and this is missed, they can simply blame the developer. There is more of an incentive for the developer to get it right than a code reviewer who is writing the tests as an ancillary task.

Comment: @RobbieDee If the receiver of blame actually matters, you have an unhealthy development environment. This is far worse than missing a few tests that would have been useful.

Comment: @jpmc26 You've missed the point slightly I feel - I wasn't passing comment on how we operate here or anywhere else, rather positing the possibility. The developer is best placed to identify possible shortcomings in their code - hence the accepted wisdom of TDD (specifically, the timely part of [FIRST](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first) principles).

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @RobbieDee's answer but I have a bit more to add.

If you really like this idea, why not have the same people write the tests before the code as executable acceptance criteria for the user story?

That would do the same thing, still keep the feedback short and get everyone to have a discussion around the story ,which I think would be of greater value.

The downsides are the danger of an endless acceptance criteria meeting :-( and I think you are trying to get people in the code review to get a look at the implementation code but I'd suggest pair programming and rotating pairs as a better solution to that problem.

The OP added an edit where they layout further details of this being a difficult or algorithm heavy feature.

In response to that I would add that your instinct of getting more eyes on the problem and solution is good. Maybe pair with multiple people one on one until everyone has seen the really difficult bit of implementation code and tests. Each throwing out new ideas and adding more value.

There is an idea sometimes call mob-programming, like pairing but with more people. This is almost what you are talking about but they help at the time of writing rather than in a formal review afterwards. This is not for everyone, and can require a strong driver (leader) to make it work, or a team that is very comfortable with each other and the process.

Doing the after the fact mob-programming I guess would have many of the same advantages of many eyes seeing the problem and and suggesting improvements and if that is how your team are comfortable operating then that can help but I would really try to keep the necessary occurrences of this down to a minimum as I think it could slow the team down.

Comment: Perhaps developers should write tests as they see fit, upload them to repository but the person doing the review should write their own tests and never look at the tests developer wrote. If both tests suites pass its all fine but if reviewer tests fail then there might be a problem?

Comment: @SokPomaranczowy adding redundancy in writing tests from different people has been tried in the past. I think if you are not doing life critical software then that is wasted effort and instead you should concentrate on where it is best to spend your time (you'll never write ALL of the tests) and with good communication in the team I think that is a much better approach.

Comment: @Encaitar I agree, this just sounds like a huge time sink that probably won't make things a whole lot better. RoI and all that ...

Answer (score 3):

Like you say, if you're running a TDD team, then this is moot since the code should already be tested.

Overall I don't think this is all that great an idea, but it depends on your current approach and what works for you. Basically, the problem I see is that you lose the "short feedback loop" advantage of tests. Getting instant notification the moment you break something even as you're writing new code is where tests really shine. If you postpone testing until code review, you are basically saying "well we COULD have fixed this issue earlier in less time and with fewer people involved, but at least we all learned something (maybe)". I'd prefer just making sure people submit tested code for review, and then you judge the correctness and maintainability of the tests. After all, code review is for reviewing, not for writing code.

On the other hand, I DO recommend you to FIDDLE with the tests/code during the review. Try to break something. Comment out an if condition. replace a boolean with a literal true/false. See if tests are failing.

But yeah, all in all, I recommend you write your tests together with your code and then review it all at once.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you are doing in code review. I think there are two main reasons for writing tests at that stage:

- first, if you do also refactoring during code review, and you note there are not enough unit tests to cover the kind of refactoring you want to apply, add such tests
- second, if the code looks to you as if it might have a bug and you want it prove (or disprove) this, write a test for it

Both cases express a need for tests which are not there at the moment, but should be. Of course, it might depend on your teams culture if these kind of tests should be written by the reviewer, or by the original author, but someone should write the tests.

Actually, I don't think this is "a corner case" just suitable for "complex, scientific algorithms" - quite the opposite, this is suitable for any kind of software you expect a certain degree of quality from.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't do it. You'll make them think TDD is horrid.

I think @k3b has it right in the comments on the question. Code written through a TDD-style process tends to look, and interact, very differently to code written without tests. Adding (good) tests to untested code usually takes a lot of refactoring the code to clarify its intent and moving parts.

By adding the tests after writing the code, you miss the architectural aspects of TDD's benefits (which to my mind are one of the major benefits). Not only that, you are asking somebody else, who is not nearly so familiar with the code, to take the hit of adding tests which are already hard to add.

Either the person adding tests will have to significantly refactor the code, or they will have to work very hard to test untestable code. Either way, they are not going to enjoy the experience. Even though this might not be classic TDD, they won't see it that way, and you could put them off TDD once and for all.

(If you're following a TDD process already, writing *additional* tests during code review would be less harmful, although in my experience, if the tests are already well-written, it's just as easy to explain the extra test to the person submitting the code for review and have them write them.)

Answer (score 1):

### Unit tests during code review are a poor substitute for unit tests during development.

What you're suggesting makes a lot of sense, intuitively. What's the review for? To check that the code is good. What are tests for? To check that the code is good. So why not combine the two?

Here's why.

**Bringing code under test is hard work.** Writing code that *just works* at the one thing it's meant to do is one thing; writing code that can be effectively and efficiently *tested* is another. Just the fact that the code now runs under two scenarios - "real work" and "test" - demands much greater flexibility, demands that that code be capable of standing on its own in a meaningful way.

Writing your code so that it's testable is extra work and skill. Refactoring somebody *else's* code for testability, when it wasn't written with testability in mind to begin with, can be a major task.

**You're duplicating effort between the developer and the reviewer.** Presumably, your developer isn't handing his code in for review without at least *some* level of confidence that it's working. *He already needs to test the code.* Now, there are different levels and scopes of testing. QA tests the code after the developer *and* the reviewer. But whatever scope you think is appropriate for the developer and reviewer, it makes no sense for the developer to figure out how to test the code to that level *once*, but make his tests throwaway and difficult to reproduce, and then bring in *the reviewer* to develop test *again*, this time ones that are automated and reproducible. You're just having *both* of them invest time in writing the same tests - once poorly, once well.

**You're turning review into a much longer, more laborious step.** If testing is a major part of the review process, *what happens when some tests fail*? Is the reviewer responsible for getting the tests all running, so she needs to debug the code as well? Or is it going to be ping-ponged back and forth, one writing tests, the other getting them to pass?

Sometimes you can write a whole bunch of tests that are all orthogonal to each other, so you don't need to ping-pong. Reviewer writes a dozen tests, half of them fail, developer fixes the bugs and all the tests remain valid, and pass now. But... plenty of the time, you've got blocker bugs, or bugs that require redesign and API changes, or whatnot. If you're tossing responsibility for passing tests back and forth between reviewer and developer, then you're not actually at the review stage. You're still developing.

**Needing to write tests doesn't incentivize more thorough review.** It basically means that the deeper you go, the more tests you have to write, and probably they'll be *hard* tests that need to go deep into the system.

Compare to the developer writing the tests, where his incentive is: if I don't write important tests, the reviewer will point that out in the review.

Even the *reviewer* will have a much better understanding of the system if she needs to go over *thorough tests of the code*, then if she needs to decide for herself when she can stop writing deep-digging test and just OK the code review.

**If the developer isn't writing unit tests, the reviewer won't either.** There are many obstacles to adopting testing as a common practice. Maybe you're under too much pressure, and your code base is hard to bring under test. Maybe you're not that experienced in testing, and feel like you can't afford the learning curve. Maybe you've got an axe murderer sending threatening notes to people who write tests. I don't know!

But whatever the cause is, it's safe to bet that it applies equally to the reviewer and to the developer. If the team is stressed out, the reviewer doesn't have any more time than the developer does (if she does, *redistribute the work so people aren't so stressed*). If nobody knows how to write unit tests well, the reviewer probably doesn't either (if she does, *she should sit down and teach her teammates*).

This suggestion sounds like trying to pass the buck from one colleague to another. And I'm just not seeing any way for that to work out well, *first and foremost* because it's really hard (and unhealthy) to create a situation where one person is the only one who can do testing, and another person can't do any testing at all.

---

What *does* work is **having the review cover tests as well.** If the developer has already written ten tests, it's much more likely the reviewer can help suggest another ten, than if the developer hadn't written any.

And, if testing corner-cases is a major task, it might make sense to distribute that more widely across the team. **Once the code is testable in the first place, writing *more* tests becomes much much easier. **

Review is a great time to *spot* corner cases. And, if the reviewer can jump in and write a test for corner cases she finds, then hey - all the better! But generally speaking, assuming that the reviewer can write tests where the developer *didn't* sounds like a very poor idea.